# Custom file template in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How I can create custom file template in VS2010? I mean when I add new item to project, i want to see MyCustomClass.cs that will contain name spaces and other things?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating your own templates in Visual Studio is not hard.

There is lots of information on MSDN:

- [Creating Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx)
- [Introduction to Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)
- [How to: Create Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx)

From that last link:

1. Create or open a project in Visual Studio.
2. Add an item to the project and modify it if you want to.
3. Modify the code file to indicate where parameter replacement should take place. For more information, see How to: Substitute Parameters in a Template.
4. On the File menu, click Export Template.
5. Click Item Template, select the project that contains the item, and click Next.
6. Select the item for which you want to create a template, and click Next.
7. Select the assembly references to include in the template, and click Next.
8. Type the icon file name, preview image, template name, and template description, and click Finish.

   The files for the template are added to a .zip file and copied to the ..\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\ folder.